# Function.prototype.apply left me with undefined is not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple function with JS like so:

```
function simple(){

}
```

I got an undefined is not a function error when I did this:

```
simple.prototype.apply(null,arguments);
```

but when I did this:

```
simple.apply(null,arguments);
```

I did not get the error, why on Earth is that?

Comment: `typeof simple.prototype === 'object'`.

Comment: objects have functions called "apply" sometimes eh

Comment: Well, only *function* objects, not generic objects (unless you add a method `apply` to it).

Comment: Just to elaborate, function objects (i.e. instances of Function) have a prototype that is a plain object, which doesn't have an *apply* method. The function itself inherits *apply* through it's internal `[[Prototype]]` which is *Function.prototype*, not its public *prototype*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.prototype` object does not have a `.apply()` method which is why your first example does not work.  `.apply()` is a method on Function objects only.  See [MDN reference for `.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).  Instead, you do something like this:

```
functionName.apply(xxx,yyy)
```

There are cases where you might see a function on the prototype object being used with `.apply()` such as:

```
Array.prototype.slice.apply(xxx,yyy)
```

But, again, that's calling `.apply()` on a function since `Array.prototype.slice` is a function.

---

In your specific example, `simple` is a function.  So, if you want to call it with a specific `this` value and/or pass it an array of arguments, then the proper syntax for that is:

```
simple.apply(xxxx, yyy)
```

That is why that syntax works - because it's the proper syntax for `.apply()`.

---

Perhaps if you share what problem you're actually trying to solve and show the relevant code we can help you more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

`simple.prototype` is `undefined`. You need `simple.__proto__` or `Function.prototype`. I.e. `prototype` property is defined on a constructor. If you want to get prototype via instance, you need `__proto__`